# html5,svg and Sql server 2008 geodata

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, svg, geolocation

I'm thinking about developing an application where I got geodata stored in a geo-database with Sql Server 2008. I like to retrieve this data and paint the different shapes with svg, embedded in html5.
My question is:
How could I possibly retrieve this data,using what? I think some script language like php would do the job. Is there a way to do that only with javascript? Also is there a way to develop that using a microsoft technology(which i would prefer).

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: A Microsoft technology? I'd suggest using C# and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I have done 2D vector graphics using SVG, based upon Garmin Edge XML Points:

http://www.mtbbikeshop.dk/ruter

Two views: Topography or Google Maps

I extacted XML data and made a lot of calulations in order to produce POLYGON points

I used PHP on server side to prepare and transform. At client end I assembled the data, using div/span

But I am not sure want kind of vector you need ?

Comment: I'm going to use svg too... I just want to render the information retrieved from the spatial database (SQL Server 2008) as shapes in svg(as shapes also stored in the database but with a different structure). Ado.Net seems quite practical I think. My question is : How can I dynamically generate svg and html code? Is Ado.Net enough or am I supposed to use JavaScript too(or something else)?

Comment: When I do SVG, I assemble the TAGS on server side. No complexity here. But doing GMaps - I did a two phase solution, DIV/SPAN hidden, then ripped and after this I call GMap. Depends ....